# Mapping signal dynamic range

Tags: power-electronics, dsp

I would like to transform a signal that has fluctuations between 1.8-1.9V (for example) to be in the range of -1V to 1V. Essentially, run it through a linear transformation [ \$y'= (y-a) \cdot b\$ ]
What is the easiest way to accomplish this with standard op amps, such that a and b are tunable (say, with a potentiometer)?

Answer (score 2):

I've used these two circuits in several different applications:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZAWTn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Inverting with variable input impedance dependent on Gain.  No interaction between Gain and Offset.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9cRzO.png)</sup>

Non-inverting with high input impedance.  Gain is slightly dependent on the Offset setting.

This doesn't answer the entire question - I'm leaving some engineering work for you to do - but it should get you started.

Comment: @ShayOhayon: I reread your example and realized that both circuits could actually work, so I removed the note saying that only one could.